# generate a Gaussian dataset in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dataset

I want to generate a Gaussian dataset. The dataset includes a total of 800 samples drawn randomly from four two-dimensional Gaussian classes with following distribution:
[image]

How can I do that with MATLAB.
I'm not expert in MATLAB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer as follow:
 (Thanks all)

```
Sigma=[0.5 0.05; 0.05 0.5];
z=mvnrnd([-3 0],Sigma,200);
x=mvnrnd([0 0],Sigma,200);
c=mvnrnd([3 0 ],Sigma,200);
v=mvnrnd([6 0 ],Sigma,200);
samples=[z; x; c; v];
plot(samples(:,1),samples(:,2),'*');
```

Answer (score 4):

The following requires Statistics Toolbox:

```
% The means of the Gaussians
mu    = [-3,0;0,0;3,0;6,0]; 

% The covariance matrix
sigma = [0.5,0.05;0.05,0.5]; 

% The mixing proportions of the Gaussians
p     = [0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25]; 

% Make a Gaussian mixture distribution
myMixtureDistribution = gmdistribution(mu,sigma,p); 

% Draw random samples from the distribution
myDataSample = myMixtureDistribution.random(800);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got following error:"??? Undefined variable "d" or class "d.random".
 "

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Start with [`randn()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/randn.html).